# How to revert apt upgrade on firefox-esr?

Tags: raspberry-pi-os, firefox

I did update/upgrade of all packages and with that my firefox-esr:68.11.0esr-1~deb10u1+rpi1 got replaced with 91.some version. It is slower, youtube is not as responsive as it used to be.

What didn't I tried to get it back, nothing really worked. The main problem is that I just can't find 68 or about 68 version of firefox package for rpi. The best I could find is .deb package in http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/f/firefox-esr/. After installing which, caused firefox to crash everytime (previous version was purged).

Where do I find binaries for firefox-esr 68 or whereabouts? Or how do I revert upgrading to 91?

Comment: maybe the **current** firefox-esr (102.9) works better

Comment: @Friendlygabe777 - ubuntu?

Comment: Restore from your backup.

Comment: @Friendlygabe777, it's raspberry pi os, not ubuntu

Comment: @Milliways, I would happily do it had I a backup

Comment: Oh, my apologies.

Comment: This question seem to be off-topic here, it is a generic Linux question

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I managed to fix it by installing a bit newer version of firefox.

I believe firefox-esr 68.11 was crashing because of some libraries incompatibilities even though installed versions were newer.

I downloaded 78.15.0esr-1~deb10u1_armhf.deb from http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/f/firefox-esr/ and did:

```
sudo apt install ./Downloads/firefox-esr_78.15.0esr-1~deb10u1_armhf.deb
```